# How to debug, why Spring Boot integration test context is not reused between tests?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, integration-testing, junit5

I got another tricky question for the crowd. I got two separate test files reusing the same Context class. I would expect them to reuse the same context, alas Spring ist started two times, prolonging the build time. Do you have any ideas how to figure out / debug, what triggers the context reload?

The test classes look like:

```
@SpringBootTest(
  classes = [HttpProxyTestContext::class]
)
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 8082)
internal class AuthOpenidConnectSpringIT {
...
}
```

and

```
@SpringBootTest(
  classes = [HttpProxyTestContext::class]
)
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 8082)
internal class AuthOidcWebClientIT {
...
}
```

The Context class is

```
@JooqTest
@ComponentScan(basePackages = ["de.denktmit.someproject.springconfig"])
class HttpProxyTestContext {}
```

Best regards, stay healthy,

Marius Schmmidt

Comment: That’s how I understand Spring Test Framework is supposed to work:. Context is kept for one test class only.

Comment: Hi @johanneslink, according to the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testing-ctx-management, if I understand it correctly, the default is reusing the context. But I somehow seem to break it, and I do not understand, how.

Comment: Hm. Ive recently had a dive into some parts of the testcontext code. The context is definitely created and stored per test class. There may be an additional cache when context is being created from same configuration. I’ll check tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to figure out, that the problem somehow arose from using @AutoConfigureWireMock(port = 8082). I found it out by experimenting with the annotations used. Finally I slightly adjusted my test setup and finally my context is reused. Here's how I did it, thats my test only config:

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = ["de.denktmit.someproject.springconfig"])
@AutoConfigureJooq
class HttpProxyTestContext {

  @Bean(destroyMethod = "stop")
  fun wiremock(): WireMockServer {
    val wireMockServer = WireMockServer(wireMockConfig().port(8082))
    wireMockServer.start()
    WireMock.configureFor("localhost", 8082);
    return wireMockServer
  }

}
```

And I just gets picked up as easy as

```
@SpringBootTest
internal class AuthOpenidConnectSpringIT {
  ...
}

@SpringBootTest
internal class AuthOidcWebClientIT {
   ...
}
```

Wiremock @BeforeEach setup left untouched and is the same as before. May it be helpful.

Good night and best regards,

Marius Schmidt